# Problem in using percentage symbol on SQL variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is part of code for SQL Server stored procedure.  @StartDate, @EndDate and @Where are parameters for the stored procedure.  Both @StartDate and @EndDate works. How can I have wild character (%) which will be used on WHERE clause for searching.

```
DECLARE 

    @Raw       NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @StartDate DATE          = '2018-11-1',
    @EndDate   DATE          = '2018-11-10',
    @WHERE     NVARCHAR      = '%Test%';

SET @Raw = 
'WITH Src (Item,Qty,[Date]) AS (SELECT Item, OrderQty, OrderDate FROM Site ' +
 'WHERE OrderDate >= ''' + CAST(@StartDate AS NVARCHAR) + ''' AND OrderDate <= ''' + CAST(@EndDate AS NVARCHAR) + ''' '  +
 'AND Item LIKE ''' + @WHERE + ''')';

SELECT @WHERE, RIGHT(@raw,15) from Site
```

The output I need is:

```
ColA    ColB
%Test%  LIKE '%Test%')
```

But, the result from the above I get is:

```
ColA    ColB
%       Item LIKE '%')
```

Comment: Why are you injecting your values and not parametrising them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem at the parameter declaration. Without the size attribute, `NVARCHAR` only keeps one char.

It should be like

```
@WHERE     NVARCHAR(50)      = '%Test%';
```

Answer (score 2):

> [ESCAPE sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):
>
> To search for any rows that contain the string `30%` anywhere in the comment column, specify a WHERE clause such as `WHERE comment LIKE '%30!%%' ESCAPE '!'`.
>
> If `ESCAPE` and the escape character aren't specified, the Database Engine returns any rows with the string `30!`.

```
WHERE ...
AND Item LIKE '!%Test!%' ESCAPE '!'
```